# Using GNU Make to compile non-existent object files

Tags: makefile

I've been learning C++ for a few months now by just using an editor and my terminal to compile and run my programs. But I saw a need to be a bit more formal with my projects, so I'm trying to learn how to build a proper project file structure and also how to use Make.

Currently, I am using GNU Make 4.1. But I am having trouble to creating object files with Make, receiving the error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'build/%.o', needed by 'main'.  Stop.
```

I've been looking all over for a solution, but none have worked so far.

Here is my makefile:

```
# Specify compiler
CC=gcc

# Specify linker
LINK=gcc

# Specify flags
CPPFLAGS = -Wall -g

# Specify directories
SRCDIR = ./src
OBJDIR = ./build

# Compile object files
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CPPFLAGS)

# Compile object files into binary
main : $(OBJDIR)/%.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: Not the downvoter but... you might want to explain why you think the makefile shown should work; how `make` processes it.  In particular, what is the function of `$(OBJDIR)/%.o` as a dependency in the final rule `main : $(OBJDIR)/%.o`?

Comment: @G.M. I'm thinking `main : $(OBJDIR)/%.o` should show that when main is executed, it depends on all the object files, which is then I call the compiler to compile all the object files together to create a binary file using. Would that be correct? `$(CC) -o $@ $^`

Comment: `%` is not a wildcard pattern; it basically matches when you have two files where substituting the percent sign in both generates a mapping which matches a file name or target name. But you have no `%` in `main`, so there is no mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the final rule...

```
# Compile object files into binary
main : $(OBJDIR)/%.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

Unfortunately `$(OBJDIR)/%.o` isn't expanded in the way in which you require.  Assuming all of your source files are in `$(SRCDIR)` you can create a variable containing their names...

```
SRCFILES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
```

Now create a variable containing the corresponding object file paths...

```
OBJFILES := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SRCFILES))
```

Now `$(OBJFILES)` should contain the list of object file paths on which `main` is dependent.  So the final rule becomes...

```
main: $(OBJFILES)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

Comment: Still no luck... Receiving this error: `make: *** No rule to make target 'build/main.o', needed by 'main'.  Stop.`

Comment: Nevermind I got it to work. Accidentally deleted the $(OBJDIR)... rule